# how to delete referenced value in mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
const UniversitySchema = new Schema({
 university_name: {
  type:String,
  
 },
 status: {
  type: String
 }

});

const CollageSchema = new Schema({
 collage_name: {
  type:String,
  required: [true,'Name field is required']
 },
 university_id: {
  type: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId ,
  ref: 'university' }]

 },
 type: {
  type:String
 }

});
```

```js
router.delete('/university/:id',function(req,res,next){
 University.findByIdAndRemove({_id:req.params.id}).then(function(detail){
  res.send(detail);
 });
});
```

I have referenced `_id` of `UniversitySchema` in `CollageSchema` and if I delete any university corresponding collage should be deleted. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an additional mongo call on `collages` collection, using [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) :

```
router.delete('/university/:id',function(req,res,next){

    const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
    const _id = ObjectId(req.params.id);

    const removeUniversity = University.findByIdAndRemove({ _id: _id });
    const removeCollage    = Collage.remove({ university_id: _id });

    Promise
        .all([removeUniversity, removeCollage])
        .then(function(values) {
            const detail = values[0];
            res.send(detail);  
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));

});
```

Comment: I am referring to "university_id" in collage table, but it will be taking any id which is not present.